# Не работает LineNR в .vimrc

Tags: vim

В заголовке всё уже написано. При введении команды `highlight LineNR ctermfg=cyan` в командную строку всё срабатывает,но эта же команда не работает в .vimrc. Как это решить?

Comment: Я не буду отправлять это как полный ответ, потому что я не уверен, что решит вашу проблему, но это работает, если вы поставите эту команду на самой последней строке? Это может быть, что установка "ColorScheme" переопределяет его, что это было для меня. (Пожалуйста, простите мой русский, я использовал Google Translate)

Comment: Спасибо сработало

Comment: Я рад слышать это! Я пост, что как реальный ответ тогда.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Параметр `LineNR` обычно меняется всегда, когда вы меняете `ColorScheme`.
Таким образом, ваши настройки будут перезаписаны, как только вы подключите цветовую схему.

Чтобы устранить эту проблему, убедитесь, что вы поместили эту установку после каких-либо настроек `ColorScheme`, тогда `LineNR` должен работать нормально.